# Typescript: using array values as union for related prop

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, react-typescript

I have the following React component

```
const Pagination = <P extends number[] = [10, 25, 50, 100]>(props: {
    perPageVariants?: P,
    perPageDefault?: P[number],
}) => 
{
    // ....
}
```

It works perfectly with default value for `perPageVariants` prop and doesn't allow to use wrong value for `perPageDefault`.
But if I set custom `perPageVariants` values, `perPageDefault` continues to allow only value from defaults.

```
<Pagination 
    perPageVariants={[123, 456]} 
    perPageDefault={100}
/>
// it works, but should throw an error
```

Is it possible to do this somehow with Typescript?

## Additional question:

Is it possible somehow to move `defaultPerPageVariants` to the external variable to have ability to configure it in one place?
I tried this, but it fails -

```
type Props<P extends number[]> = {
  perPageVariants?: [...P],
  perPageDefault?: [...P][number],
}

const defaultPerPageVariants = [10, 25, 50, 100, 200] as const;

const Pagination = <P extends number[] = typeof defaultPerPageVariants>(props: Props<P>) => {
  const {
    perPageVariants = defaultPerPageVariants,
    perPageDefault = defaultPerPageVariants[0],
  } = props;

  return null;
};
```

It fails with the following error -

> Type 'readonly [10, 25, 50, 100, 200]' does not satisfy the constraint 'number[]'. The type 'readonly [10, 25, 50, 100, 200]' is 'readonly' and cannot be assigned to the mutable type 'number[]'.

But I can't define `defaultPerPageVariants` without `as const` because it will be `number[]` type and break restriction for `perPageDefault` prop in case if `perPageVariants` is not specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to infer each element in the tuple:

```js
import React from 'react'

const Pagination = <P extends number[] = [10, 25, 50, 100]>(props: {
  perPageVariants?: [...P],
  perPageDefault?: [...P][number],
}) => {
  return null
}

<Pagination perPageDefault={1} perPageVariants={[123, 456]} />;// expected error
<Pagination perPageDefault={123} perPageVariants={[123, 456]} />; // ok
```

[enter link description here](https://tsplay.dev/w1PyGW)

Answer (score 1):

Answer to the additional question -

```
type Props<P extends number[]> = {
  perPageVariants?: [...P],
  perPageDefault?: [...P][number],
}

const defaultPerPageVariants = [10, 25, 50, 100, 200] as const;

const Pagination = <
  P extends number[] = [...typeof defaultPerPageVariants]
>(props: Props<P>) => {
  const {
    perPageVariants = defaultPerPageVariants,
    perPageDefault = defaultPerPageVariants[0],
  } = props;

  return null;
};
```